# Postgres - Get sum of the values in a column on condition of another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in Postgres (`custdata`) that looks like this:

```
customerid | mID | count
    1         3      13
    1         2      17
    1         2       3
    1         5      14
    1         4       7
```

And a query like this:

```
SELECT
c.customerid,
c.mID,
c.count,
SUM (c.count)
FROM custdata c
JOIN tableB b
ON b.customerid = c.customerid
WHERE c.mID <> 2
AND b.starttimestamp = ? and b.endtimestamp = ?
```

I want to get the sum of the values in the `count` column of the values whose `mID` does not equal 2. In this case, the correct sum would be 34. But in my case, the result is returning 2 different rows with the incorrect sum. How can I get the sum of the values in the `count` column where the `mID` is not 2? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If your result is 2 rows, then you used `GROUP BY`. Also, your query is invalid without a `GROUP BY`. Please post the query you ran & clarify your expected results. (F.ex. should the sum be calculated per `customerid`s?)

Answer (score 2):

Hoping, i understood correctly.
Please check below query

```
SELECT
c.customerid,
c.mID,
c.count,
SUM(case when c.mID<>2 then  c.count else 0  end) over(partition by c.customerid order by c.customerid) sum_col
FROM custdata c
JOIN tableB b
ON b.customerid = c.customerid
WHERE
--c.mID <> 2 AND
b.starttimestamp = ? and b.endtimestamp = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

With window function you can group with customerID:

```
SELECT
c.customerid,
c.mID,
c.count,
SUM(c.count) over(partition by c.customerid)
FROM custdata c
JOIN tableB b using(customerid)
WHERE c.mID <> 2
group by c.customerid,
c.mID,
c.count
```